# Lenovo L530 stuck at startup

Tags: windows, lenovo-laptop

A full scan from Windows defender was taking place when I shut down my PC(Windows 10 - I had just uninstalled McAfee so Windows Defender took over immediately).

The following morning, my Lenovo L530 won't start up. It stays stuck in the splash screen.

I have tried:
1. Unplug all USB ports, extra monitors, , power plug, turned off the wireless but still no response stays stuck
2. Tried entering setup(hitting F1 once splash screen appears) , although i hear the sound it still remains stuck with an indication 'Entering Setup', same for Boot Menu(F12).

What else should I try to fix this?

In the worst case if i wanted to format my OS how would I do that if it cannot boot from DVD drive?

Answer (score 1):

since it's not even going to the boot menu, have you tried to open the laptop completely and re-seat the DIMM cards? I found a forum wherein there's a tutorial on what to look for and what to double check on the laptop (though this is for a different lenovo series, this might help):

- https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-L-R-and-SL-series/ThinkPad-hangs-on-boot-stuck-at-Thinkpad-screen/ta-p/301526

By the way, when you're entering the boot menu, are you sure that there's no dvd drive or flash drives plugged in on any usb ports? Ensure to remove those first before entering BIOS.

Comment: Hi Jim nothing was attached in any USB ports-  I fixed it by removing the battery and re-inserting it. It then started up normally from where it left off.

Comment: Hi, that's good to hear that it started up normally. My suggestion is for you to ran some diagnostics which lenovo has and might as well use their driver update package from their website just to ensure things are on the same page :) Cheers!